# OutOfMemoryException when I execute RDLC ReportViewer WebForms ASPNet

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, out-of-memory

I use VS 2012 , asp.net 4.5.1, and **ReportViewer** (`Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms` and local *RDLC files*).

Now, in production environment I get the error **OutOfMemoryException** and **LocalProcessingException**, using output format as **Excel xlsx and PDF files**

I use `localReport.Render` for get bytes and send to client using `Response.BinaryWrite`

> ```
>   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
> ```
>
> Void Unload(System.AppDomain)
>           at System.AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain domain)
>           at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext
>   context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean
>   generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ReportSnapshotBase&
>   snapshot)
>           at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.CompileReport()
>           at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.get_Snapshot()
>           at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContext
>   context, Boolean rebuild, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
>           at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContext
>   itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
>           at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.CompileReport()
>
> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException,
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>
> ```
>     An error occurred during local report processing
> ```

My code:

```
var reporteDataSourceClients = new ReportDataSource("ClientsMyReport", lstClient);
localReport.DataSources.Add(reporteDataSourceClients);

MyReport.GenerateMyReport(OutputType.Excel, localReport, "MyReport Clients");
public static void GenerateMyReport(OutputType outputType, LocalReport localReport, string titleMyReport)
{
    try
    {
        string reportType = outputType.ToString();
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><SimplePageHeaders>False</SimplePageHeaders></DeviceInfo>";

        byte[] renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        switch (outputType)
        {
            case OutputType.Pdf:
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                break;
            case OutputType.Excel:
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + titleMyReport + "." + fileNameExtension);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
    catch (LocalProcessingException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Any sugesstions?

Comment: Note that even once you fix the out of memory exception, you're going to get a ThreadAbortException from `Response.End`. You can either use a different function or overload that doesn't cause that error, or ignore it in your catch block.

Comment: Do you get the error every time? Or does it work at first and then stop working later?

Comment: In PRE environment is ok, but in PRO environment now fails every time. (***How can I know all user connected with sessión in my asp.net application?***)

Comment: That sounds like a different question to me.